# PHP Merge two arrays in to each other, using an index array as a reference - Two arrays as output

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am trying to take two arrays, and merge them to each other. The first array serves as an 'index' array, that is - that is the format that the output arrays desirably would be:

```
$array1 = [
    'DIV1' => 'Some element data',
    'SUPPLEMENTAL' => [
        'RPC' => '10.24.122.32',
        'PORT' => '8080'
    ],
    'ASG' =>  'some arbitrary data'
];

$array2 = [
    'DIV2' => 'Some more element data',
    'ASG'  => 'different arbitrary data',
    'DIV1' => 'Some element data that refers to the other object'
    'SUPPLEMENTAL' => [
         'RPC' => '10.24.123.1'
    ]
];
```

So after the merge, we would effectively have two arrays. This can be done as a a single function called twice, which passes each array as parameters (reversed for the second call - and somehow defining the index array). The keys would be carried over -only-, no values. We would end up with arrays looking like this:

```
$array1 = [
    'DIV1' => 'Some element data', 
    'DIV2' => '',                       // blank because only key was moved
    'SUPPLEMENTAL' => [
        'RPC' => '10.24.122.32',
        'PORT' => '8080'
    ],
    'ASG' =>  'some arbitrary data'
];

$array2 = [
    'DIV1' => 'Some element data that refers to the other object'
    'DIV2' => 'Some more element data',
    'SUPPLEMENTAL' => [
         'RPC' => '10.24.123.1',
         'PORT' => ''                   // blank because only key was moved
    ],
    'ASG'  => 'different arbitrary data'
];
```

It is not -extremely- important that the imported (blank) keys are put in some order, but the preservation of order of existing elements is important. As long as it abides by the index arrays order definition (array1 in this case).

I think I would need to do some sort of nested sort for the multiple dimensions.

Comment: I think DIV1 in output of array 2 will not be blank

Comment: @Rahul what do you mean? I am looking for a procedure which will move the missing keys and set the values to empty strings/null.

Comment: DIV1 is not missing from array2 so it should not be blank

Comment: @Rahul - you are absolutely right. My mistake! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your data doesn't have keys in the same order it'll be difficult to maintain key order, but you can achieve what you need with a recursive function:

```
function recursiveReKeyArrays(array $array1, array $array2)
{
    // Loop through the array for recursion
    foreach ($array2 as $key => $value) {
        if (!is_array($value)) {
            continue;
        }

        $array1[$key] = recursiveReKeyArrays($array1[$key], $value);
    }

    // Find the differences in the keys
    foreach (array_diff_key($array2, $array1) as $key => $value) {
        $array1[$key] = null;
    }

    return $array1;
}
```

This will loop through the second array, find any values which are arrays and recurse into them and find any missing keys and set them to `null`.

This will give you this output:

```
Array
(
    [DIV1] => Some element data
    [SUPPLEMENTAL] => Array
        (
            [RPC] => 10.24.122.32
            [PORT] => 8080
        )

    [ASG] => some arbitrary data
    [DIV2] => 
)
Array
(
    [DIV2] => Some more element data
    [ASG] => different arbitrary data
    [DIV1] => Some element data that refers to the other object
    [SUPPLEMENTAL] => Array
        (
            [RPC] => 10.24.123.1
            [PORT] => 
        )

)
```

Example here: http://ideone.com/5ml1y4